# Unable To Access Azure Active Directory Getting 403 Error code

Tags: azure, active-directory

I am new to Azure and i was trying to create user in Azure AD but while i am clicking on the service No Access error coming with Error code 403 . Pl help to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

403 means you don’t have permissions. To add or delete users you must be a User administrator or Global administrator Double check your permission’s according to [Azure AD documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-users-assign-role-azure-portal)